# Nougat is much slower when compared to marshmallow

Tags: java, android, performance, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-7.0-nougat

I've been making an android game and I noticed that it runs more than twice as slow on Nougat than on Marshmallow.  In fact I figured out that between any two points in my code it seems to have roughly the same increase in time.

So I made a test application that, when the back button is pressed, does a test but I got roughly the same result again (code is below).  I tested this using two android virtual devices(see the code for an average time in ms that was recorded) but I initially noticed it because my tablet got updated to nougat so it isn't AVD specific.

I'm stumped as to what is causing this.  Some ideas I've had are the following:

- The compiler isn't optimizated for nougat (api min is 15 and target is 25 and I'm building with sdk tools 25.0.2).  Seems unlikely to me since it would be a pretty widespread issue that google would immediately fix.
- The OS is using more resources and thus there are less left over for my game.  Unlikely since this shouldn't account for a 2X decrease in speed.
- The OS is added in a smaller limit for CPU usage.  Maybe I have to request to be high priority or something alike however I'd expected clear documentation so also unlikely.
- Android studio's settings for me aren't optimal.  This one seems the most likely to me but I can't find anything that helps me yet.

Any insights or reproductions are appreciated!  Thanks.

MainActivity

```
package com.example.nickgkg.test;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
  TextView text;
  long time = 0;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    text = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.text);
  }
  @Override
  public void onBackPressed(){
    //API 24(nougat) vs API 23(marshmallow)
    //API 25 performs the same as API 24 so I didn't include it
    long t=System.nanoTime();
    if(false){//Toggle this to change the test
      float garbage;
      for(int i=0;i<100000000;i++)
        garbage=i*27/2200f;
      //API 24:710ms vs API 23:620ms
    }else{
      for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++)
        something();
      //API 24:320ms vs API 23:120ms
    }
    time=System.nanoTime() - t;
    text.setText(time/1000000f+"ms");
  }
  private void something(){
    //BLANK function call
  }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.nickgkg.test.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:id="@+id/text"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: On different make 23 devices you will see the same spread in times. Depending on cpu.

Comment: Your test, if the figures reported are correct, demonstrate 200 nanoseconds additional overhead per method invocation (200ms / 1000000). That should not result in "2X decrease in speed" unless you have a lot of tiny method invocations (e.g., each with an average of 200 nanoseconds internal computation time).

Comment: @greenapps I'm using android virtual devices for both 23 and 24 with the exact same specs so nothing should be device specific

Comment: @CommonsWare Invocations are just an example of something that is slower.  The arithmetic operations are also slower for example (620 vs 710) and I'm sure other stuff is slower too since how else would I get a 2X decrease in speed.  I don't want to test every type of code so I figured showing just two was a good start

Comment: Dont spend your time on virtual devices.

Comment: "The arithmetic operations are also slower for example (620 vs 710)" -- at a pace of 90 femtoseconds per pair of floating-point operations. "how else would I get a 2X decrease in speed" -- use method tracing, with your actual app, and determine where you are spending your time in your actual app.

Comment: Well I had a tablet using marshmallow then I updated it to nougat and then my game ran twice as slow as compared to when it was on marshmallow.  As to check if it was only my table I used some virtual devices but I got the same result.  I can't think that that's a coincidence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating android studio fixed the problem 
(updated from 2.2 to 2.3).  I'm still not sure why this happened in the first place but I think it might have been that the debug builds for nougat weren't being optimized as much as the debug builds for marshmallow.  On another note; perhaps if I tested with release builds instead of debug builds then I would never have got this issue (haven't tested this though).

Comment: Android Studio 2.3 is the latest

Comment: @cricket_007 My mistake.  Thanks for pointing that out!  Fixed now